# How can I defeat Zemouregal in The World Wakes?

Tags: runescape

I have tried fighting Zemouregal several times with different strategies, and I have never gotten past the second stage of purple portals. He doesn't seem to have a weakness to any damage type, so I can't approach it that way. I know that he uses magic attacks, but his zombies use all kinds of damage, so I'm not sure what kind of armor to use either.

Basically, what type of equipment/inventory should I bring with me and what strategy should I use to defeat him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to defeat Zemouregal with magic, wearing mystic armor and carrying a mystic battlestaff. My inventory had air runes and a couple of prayer potions, and the rest was monkfish (the most effective food for my level).

In battle, I used Fire Wave on autocast and used the four basic magic abilities (Wrack, Impact, Combust, and Chain) frequently as possible and the ultimate ability Omnipower whenever I filled up my adrenaline. The basic strategy in battle is to simply attack the dark portals whenever possible, and attack Zemouregal otherwise. Ignore the pink portals, since attacking them simply uses time that could be spent attacking Zemouregal.

Comment: So you answered your own question and then accepted it. To me that shows that you aren't open to new ideas.

Comment: You must be joking. Ignoring the fact that I asked this question over 6 months ago, and the *only* other answer is 45 minutes old, self-answering is an accepted and useful part of this site, *and* I waited a full day before I answered my own question.

Comment: That's fine to self-answer. I just don't approve of self-acceptance. But that's my opinion.

Comment: My answer was the correct answer and the only one that helped me. And, on this question, I only need one answer because it's a one-time boss fight, so I only need to beat it once. So there's no reason why I shouldn't accept this answer.

Comment: As part of a Q/A site the questions and answers shouldn't just be about the asker (yet that is a key component) However it should be used for the public as well so that if someone hasn't completed the quest then there can always be more than one answer.

Comment: Acceptance *is* entirely about the asker. That's why only the asker can accept an answer, and any suggestion to the contrary is quickly shot down. Acceptance means that the answer is the one that helped *me* the most, so I am not obligated to wait for another answer before accepting my own. People are still free to post other answers and vote on those answers.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've made it yet but wear magic armour and attack with range. You MUST kill the blue portals before he takes any damage. Ignore the purple portals, just stay out of their way as they drain your health.

I just used royal dragon armour, addy darts, and prayed against magic, took Rocktails in that was it.

If there is a build up of zombies around you, just run away from them to a clear spot and some not all stop attacking